# Windows.Forms and gtk# interoperability?

Tags: c#, winforms, interop, gtk#

Can I combine code that uses System.Drawing.Bitmap together with other code in a program that uses GTK#?
I would like to be able to display the Bitmap image processed in a GTK# window/widget.

More generally, is there any interoperability between the two toolkits?
For example is there any classes, like Rectangle, that would work on both, or perhaps a wrapper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Drawing isn't really specific to WinForms, and it's at the very least possible to [get Graphics instances from Gdk.Drawables](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T:Gtk.DotNet.Graphics) in Gtk#.